# How to find registered users from phone contacts

Tags: android, ios, react-native, architecture, contacts

I am writing a simple app (in React Native, but that shouldn't make a difference) where users can register and then see a list of their phone contacts that are ALSO registered. It basically connects users that have each other saved in their phones, similar to Whatsapp.

My question is, how do I do that?

I see two options:

1. When looking for "friends", send all of the user's contacts to the server and compare them there with the list of registered users in the database (which doesn't feel quite right, I mean mining all of your users' contacts without those contacts' permission?), or
2. Download all users from the Database to the phone and compare them there (which is obviously out of the question)

Is there a ***third*** way that I'm not thinking of?

[edit]: thank you for taking the time to answer, but it's not really all that helpful so far. I mean, obviously I'm going to encrypt the stuff :D

I would like to know if there's a third way to architect this that I haven't thought of. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in both cases (1 & 2), you will have to ask your users for a permission to access Contact book.

As a third option in combination with first, if the privacy of your users concerns you (it probably should), you can use an MD5 or SHA1 (any hashing algorithm, you name it) algos on the phone numbers and use the result instead of the real phone numbers. They will be unique for each unique phone number and can't be decoded back into phone number itself.

[The first thing I googled.](https://gist.github.com/khanlou/baf60dd62601b879eeba209943b04973) (Swift example) But you will have to include a CommonCrypto to the file.

I'm sure you will be able to find this algorithms for react native as well, if needed.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the former answer maybe better use SHA-256 (in Java you would use `MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256").digest()` from the `java.security` package) for hashing the sanitized phone numbers from the address book if available in React Native.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar using "react-native-contacts" you can find out more about it here: https://github.com/rt2zz/react-native-contacts

Once you have integrated react-native-contacts, you will be able to read all contacts stored on your users device, then you could try to post them through to your backend that would have . a function that matches the specific users contacts.

As stated by T. Pasichnyk and Norbert, you should take the neccessary steps to secure your user's data